# Given two blocks of text, how can I generate a coefficient to compare how similar they are?

Tags: c#, diff

Basically, I'm not looking for specific differences as you would get with a normal diff algorithm, I'm looking more to generate some sort of numeric value which represents the level of difference of two blocks of text so that I can take a bunch of different text blocks and extract a set of those text blocks that qualify as being sufficiently unique from each other. Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance).